# C++でオブジェクトを初期化するとエラーが出る

Tags: c++, arduino

以下のコードでエラーが出てしまいます。

エラー内容
main.cpp:5:44:error: use of deleted function 'SerialPrint::SerialPrint()'
     SerialPrint _serialPrint = SerialPrint();

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
// SerialPrint _serialPrint;

void setup(){
    SerialPrint _serialPrint = SerialPrint();
    _serialPrint.beginPrint(DEBUG_PORT_RX, DEBUG_PORT_TX, DEBUG_PORT_BAUDRATE);
}

void loop(){

}
```

main.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SerialPrint.h"

#define DEBUG_PORT_RX 11
#define DEBUG_PORT_TX 12
#define DEBUG_PORT_BAUDRATE 4800

void setup();
void loop();
```

SerialPrint.cpp

```
#include "SerialPrint.h"
#include <string.h>

/**
 * コンソール表示用シリアルポート初期化
 * */

void SerialPrint::beginPrint(uint8_t rx, uint8_t tx, long baudrate) {
    _serial = SoftwareSerial(rx,tx);
    _serial.begin(baudrate);
}

void SerialPrint::print(const char *message) {
    _serial.print(message);
}

void SerialPrint::print(String message) {
    _serial.print(message);
}

void SerialPrint::println(const char *message) {
    _serial.println(message);
}

void SerialPrint::println(String message) {
    _serial.println(message);
}
```

SeriapPrint.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


class SerialPrint {
public:
    void beginPrint(uint8_t rx, uint8_t tx, long baudrate);
    // static void cmpStr(const char *str1, const char *str2, char *buf);
    void print(const char * message);
    void println(const char * message);
    void print(String message);
    void println(String message);
private:
    SoftwareSerial _serial;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

main.cppの`setup()`関数の中の

```
SerialPrint _serialPrint = SerialPrint();
```

で、`SerialPrint`クラスのインスタンスを生成しています。このとき、`SerialPrint`クラスのすべてのメンバー変数も初期化されます。この場合は`SoftwareSerial _serial;`も一緒に初期化されます。`SerialPrint()`のデフォルトコンストラクタは作っていないので、メンバーもすべてデフォルトコンストラクタで初期化されます。

[Arduinoのマニュアル](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialConstructor)を見ると`SoftwareSerial`クラスにはデフォルトコンストラクタがないようです。このため、`SoftwareSerial _serial;`が初期化できず、エラーになっています。

実際`SerialPrint::beginPrint()`メソッドの中では、`SoftwareSerial`のコンストラクタに引数を渡しているので、これを`SoftwareSerial`のコンストラクタで行えばいいと思います。